# Classification of $Z_7 \rtimes Z_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to classify $Z_7 \rtimes Z_6 \cong Z_2 \times Z_3$, but I have a question about it...

The possible homomorphisms are:

1) $\alpha$ is trivial, so $G \cong Z_7 \times Z_6$

2) Kernel of $\alpha$ = $Z_3$. So $G \cong Z_7 \rtimes (Z_2 \times Z_3) \cong (Z_7 \rtimes Z_2) \times Z_3 = D_{14} \times Z_3$.

3) Kernel of $\alpha$ = $Z_2$. So $G \cong Z_7 \rtimes (Z_2 \times Z_3) = (Z_7 \rtimes Z_3) \times Z_2 \cong Z_2 \times \text{(nonabelian group of order 21)}$. This nonabelian group of order 21 cannot be the dihedral or the quaternionic groups because the order is not even, right? It cannot be the symmetry or klien groups either. So do I just leave it this way, or do I need to continue?

4) Kernel of $\alpha$ = $\{e\}$. So $G \cong Z_7 \rtimes Z_6$. This can't be isomorphic to the dihedral or quaternionic groups either, because it has a normal subgroup of order 7...and if it was dihedral or quaternionic, then the only normal subgroup would be of order 12, right? It can't be the symmetric or the klien groups either. So I'm also stuck with this. Is it ok to leave it this way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to classify the semidirect products $\Bbb{Z}_{7} \rtimes \Bbb{Z}_{6}$, that is, $\Bbb{Z}_{7} \rtimes \Bbb{Z}_{7}^{\times}$?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti No it's not $Z_7$, it is $Z^{\times}_7$. So I want to classify $Z^{\times}_7 \rtimes Z_6$.

Comment: Because in all of your cases I see a $\Bbb{Z}_{7}$... if it's really $\Bbb{Z}_{7}^{\times} \rtimes \Bbb{Z}_{6}$, this is a group of order $36$.

Comment: I am puzzled: The multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z_7}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_6$.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Oh I'm sorry...I was confusing the homomorphism $Z_6 \rightarrow Z^{\times}_7$ with the semidirect product $Z_7 \rtimes Z_6$. Yes, you're right.

Comment: OK, please fix the title and the first line.

Comment: Four hours passed by and the OP didn't correct his own post so we don't really know what he meant. I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of comments on cases (3) and (4).

3) The group of order $21$ is the semidirect product of $\Bbb{Z}_{7}$ by $\langle b \rangle$, where the element $b$ of order $3$ acts as
$$
x \mapsto 2 x.
$$
(Check that this is an automorphism of order $3$ of $\Bbb{Z}_{7}$.)

4) The group here is the semidirect product of $\Bbb{Z}_{7}$ by $\langle c \rangle$, where the element $c$ of order $6$ acts as
$$
x \mapsto 3 x.
$$
(Check that this is an automorphism of order $6$ of $\Bbb{Z}_{7}$.)

Comment: For 4), we have the homomorphism $Z_6 \rightarrow Z^{\times}_7$, right? Since $Z_6 \cong Z^{\times}_7$, this is the same homomorphism as $Z^{\times}_7 \rightarrow Z^{\times}_7$. Also, we know that $a^7 \cong a$ for all a in $Z^{\times}_7$. So does this mean that it is the frobenius map? Or does it have nothing to do with it? Thank you in advance.